# Using C++ libraries in VS Code (Winsock)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm coding on Visual Studio for a simple UDP socket application on windows, for which I need the ws2_32.lib library.
Now, in Visual Studio I'm using

```
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

to link the needed library.

What about moving on VS Code? How can I use that library then? Aside from the C++ extension, do I need a particular compiler?
Since the complete IDE essentially does all by itself, I'm pretty new to the problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you use gcc I don't know if it works, but you can use MS-C++ compiler then it also works in VSC

Comment: "What about the same thing but moving on VS Code?" - What is this supposed to mean? Do you wish to find out how to link a library without using `#pragma` statements?

Comment: @enhzflep yes sorry, I basically don't know how to link the library in VSCode. Since I don't have the full IDE always available, I would like to do everything with just Code (and of course the correct compiler).

Comment: `#pragma comment (lib` only works on MSVC. Assuming you use GCC (MinGW) with VSC, you need to link the library manually, by adding `-lws2_32` to the flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add properties in tasks.json in VS Code. This is the test demo **DLLProject.lib**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            ...
            ...
            "args": [
                ......
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "DLLProject.lib"
            ],
```

.CPP

```
#include"DLLProject.h"
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to run the compiler just fine editing the .json